# Crash report not getting in Crashlytics / fabric. Showing Warning : “It looks like we are missing dSYMs to process crashes for the versions below.”

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

I tired to resolve dSYM file issue.
I’ve updated project settings of the project and target **Debug Information Format** to **DWARF with dSYM File** also I’ve updated dSYM file and successfully updated but every time getting **We're processing the uploaded dSYM(s). Please check back in a few minutes for the status.**
But still dSYM file not uploaded and Crash reports are not generated in fabric/ crashlytics for my iOS application.

Anyone please help me to get out of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Sometimes uploading in a .zip format helps fasten things up. Go to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ , select your app. Click on Activity and then on All Builds. Tap on your build -> download dSYM zip file. Now upload and wait for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Now working fine:

```
// Objective-C
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

// Swift
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download dSYMs from app store connect (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) and upload to crashlytics.

Got to the app store connect (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com)

App Store -> My App -> Activity

you can see "Includes Symbols" on Activity. you can download from there and upload to crashlytics.

[image]

App Store -> My App -> Activity